# Is it possible to give the server access to the clients USB devices over SSH, or other medium

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

Sorry if I use some wrong terminology here, I am still learning some.

So, I have a laptop running Ubuntu, and I have a Pi Zero W running Kali. On my laptop, I've flashed a Logitech Dongle for tinkering around with the MouseJack exploit. I have been wondering if it is possible to route the traffic to and from the Dongle to the Pi Zero running Kali. And if so, are there more than one way of doing so? I've also been tinkering around with accessing the Pi Zero via USB, a la plug n' play style.

Basically, can I treat my laptops USB ports as the Pi Zeros "USB ports"

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check this [Using a remote host's USB port as local USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837277/using-a-remote-hosts-usb-port-as-local-usb-linux-and-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is *possible*, with [usbip](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB/IP).

I'm actually using a rpi0w as a way to turn my wired usb printer into a wireless one.

HOWEVER, despite the kernel/userland interface being very simple -- in order to export or import a device you just pass an open socket to the kernel, by writing its fd number into some `/sys` files,

The userland usbip "utilities" are so utterly inept and misdesigned, that being able to *safely* forward USB devices over SSH has turned into a 100 lines, very ugly and fragile script (involving iptables rules, pidfiles and other junk) that I will not post here.

I think that could be done much simpler and better, and if I'm ever able to do it, I'll add a github link here ;-)